# Fixed Side - CSS - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the clapping of the upper part of the clapper but, the upper part is not getting fixed and moves on the hover. Thanks for help :)

[image]

CSS:

```
.clapperboard{
     width: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 290%; left: 23%;
 } 
 .clipUp{ width: 48%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 155%;
     left: 23%;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

 .clipUp:hover{
     transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  /* -webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);
   transform:rotate(15deg);*/ 
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: .clapperboard
{
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 290%;
    left: 23%;
}
.clipUp{
    width: 48%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 155%;
    left: 23%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.clipUp:hover{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  /*  -webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);
            transform:rotate(15deg);*/
}

Comment: Sorry, I am learning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sum, not just the CSS. Please update your post with all of the HTML, CSS, and JS/jQuery you have so far. Posting it in the code box would be best, or creating a codepen/fiddle out of it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/milnikola81/pen/GNLvrv

Comment: I am trying to achieve the effects from this codepen

Comment: All of the code you need is in the codepen. What's the problem? You haven't posted your code where "the upper part is not getting fixed and moves on the hover." Again, please provide all of the code you have so far.